# More Code Assist in Eclipse PDT For HTML

Tags: html, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt, code-assist

I am trying to come over from dreamweaver to eclipse.

In eclipse when I am in a php file writing html. If I just type a "<" then the code assist popup will come up with all the options I can choose from.

I would like to know if the code assist can appear in more places though.

If I type `"<div"` and hit space can I get another code assist popup? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `"<div"` (or any other tag), just enter a space and then hit `Ctrl+Space`:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/3842/20100523012342.jpg](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/3842/20100523012342.jpg)